# Laravel distance query in repository

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.4 and I want to use distance in Eloquent.

In my repository, I have :

```
public function getRecommended($lat, $lng, $distance, $n)
{
    \DB::enableQueryLog();
    $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( ad_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( ad_longitude ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( ad_latitude ) ) ) ) ) AS distance');

    $data = $this->queryGetAds()->addSelect($raw)->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )->groupBy('distance')->having('distance', '<=', $distance)->paginate($n);
    dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
}
```

The error is :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in
>   'group statement'

I checked by removing

```
->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )->groupBy('distance')->having('distance', '<=', $distance)
```

And the debugging shows the good query with $raw statement in. I am in a repository.

Is there something missing ?

Comment: You cannot group by a column alias.

Comment: I tried to remove the group statement, the error is still here.

Comment: If you remove the group statement, you also need to remove the having statement.

Comment: So, how can I check the distance ? I need to have the distance < 100 here.